# working Multiple opened browsers of same kind

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

How to work on different opened browsers of the same kind.. I worked on a single browser of IE or Firefox by addressing it as "@browser...."

Answer (score 0):

Just create a second instance of a browser object  e.g. you make a @browser1 and an @browser2